# RobotFramework: Global variables which change only locally

Tags: robotframework

In the root of the test directory, I have this `setting.robot` file which includes the global variables used in all test suites and test cases. This file has been used as `resource` in all test cases:

```
*** Variables ***
${Variable1}       value1
${Variable2}       value2
${Variable3}       value3
${Variable4}       value4
...
```

Now suppose this is the test hierarchy I have:

> -- Suite1
>   ------ Test1
>   ------ Test2
>   -- Suite2
>   ------ Test3
>   ------ Test4

I might need to change the value of `${Variable1}` in `Test1`, so in the `setup` of `Test1` I use this code:

```
Set Global Variable    ${Variable1}    NewValue
```

The problem with this approach is the I am changing the value globally, and this will affect the other tests. Another solution is to use `Set Variable`:

```
${Variable1}=    Set Variable    NewValue
```

The problem with this method is that this variable change does not affect the lower level `user keywords`:

> Prior to Robot Framework 2.9 variables in the local scope leaked to
>   lower level user keywords. This was never an intended feature, and
>   variables should be set or passed explicitly also with earlier
>   versions.

So how can I have global variables which can be changed per test case when needed without affecting other tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Robot Framework environment to test right now but I think you can use:

```
BuiltIn.Set test variable    ${variable1}    value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Set Test Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable) as the previous answer mentioned.

This keyword :

> Makes a variable available everywhere within the scope of the current test.
>   Variables set with this keyword are available everywhere within the scope of the currently executed test case. For example, if you set a variable in a user keyword, it is available both in the test case level and also in all other user keywords used in the current test. Other test cases will not see variables set with this keyword.